# Running nested commands at host via vagrant triggers plugin

Tags: ruby, plugins, triggers, command, vagrant

I am trying to copy back few files from guest to host using vagrant triggers plugin and scp.

Using scp over ssh as:

`scp -r -P 2209 -i .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1:/guest/path/to/file host_path`

Using `2209` port above since `vagrant ssh-config` is showing me the mapped host port is `2209`.

To avoid manual look up of host-port, modified the command as

`scp -r -P $(vagrant ssh-config | grep Port | grep -o '[0-9]+') -i .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1:/guest/path/to/file host_path`

this works on host as expected, however while given to `run` in `config.trigger` block, it does not seem be evaluated.

What could be the way to run the nested commands using triggers plugin at host?

Edit -1 : Posting the trigger block as per the Marc's comment

```
  config.trigger.after :provision do
    run "mkdir -p host_sync"
    hport_cmd = "$(vagrant ssh-config | grep Port | grep -o '[0-9]\+')"

    run "scp -r -P " + hport_cmd +  " -i .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1:/guest/path/to/file/* host_sync"

  end
```

Comment: Can you post the config.trigger block?
I've had success doing oddities like this by using bare ruby execution before the vagrant configure

Comment: @MarcYoung: I have updated the question with `config.trigger` block

Answer (score 1):

Following `trigger` block is yielding results as expected.

```
  config.trigger.after :provision do
    run "mkdir -p host_sync"
    hport = `vagrant ssh-config`.split("\n  ").find{|e| e.start_with?("Port") }.split(" ")[1] 
    run "scp -r -P #{hport} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1:/guest/path/to/file/*  host_sync"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making that hport_cmd a full ruby eval as hport = %x[vagrant ssh-config | grep Port | grep -o '[0-9]+'] in the top of your Vagrantfile (above the configure altogether, literally on line 1 such as

```
hport = %x[vagrant ssh-config | grep Port | grep -o '[0-9]\+']
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 ...snip...

config.trigger.after :provision do
  run "mkdir -p host_sync"
  run "scp -r -P " + #{hport} +  " -i .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1:/guest/path/to/file/* host_sync"

end
```

Comment: I tried this however I am getting `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end`. Thank you for your reply!  More over, I think the value of command `vagrant ssh-config` will yield only inside the `trigger` block since by time execution reaches the provision step, box is already up, which otherwise is not guaranteed.